# spree_product_assembly crashes in production

Tags: heroku, spree

I'm setting up a Spree Commerce site. I am running 2-4-Stable, as many of the extensions I need will not work on 3-0-Stable. I set up the site with everything but product_assembly and it works perfect. Add it and it runs fine on my nitriou.io box, push it to heroku and everything dies.

heroku log --tail

```
2015-09-10T02:50:47.477434+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-09-10T02:50:52.594597+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}`
2015-09-10T02:50:55.340137+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2015-09-10T02:50:55.340170+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 2.13.4 (ruby 2.0.0-p645), codename: A Midsummer Code's Dream
2015-09-10T02:50:55.340172+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2015-09-10T02:50:55.340174+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290579+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/spree-product-assembly-a932f58d19f2/app/serializers/spree/wombat/assembly_shipment_ser
ializer.rb:3:in `<module:Wombat>': uninitialized constant Spree::Wombat::ShipmentSerializer (NameError)
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290582+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/spree-product-assembly-a932f58d19f2/app/serializers/spree/wombat/assembly_ship
ment_serializer.rb:2:in `<module:Spree>'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290584+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/spree-product-assembly-a932f58d19f2/app/serializers/spree/wombat/assembly_ship
ment_serializer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290585+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290588+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290590+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290591+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290592+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290595+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290598+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290601+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290602+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290605+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290608+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.289678+00:00 app[web.1]: ! Unable to load application: NameError: uninitialized constant Spree::Wombat::ShipmentSerializer
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290611+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290612+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290613+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290617+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290618+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290621+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290622+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290625+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290628+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290632+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290633+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290636+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `require'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290639+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290642+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/rack/builder.rb:184:in `instance_eval'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290643+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/rack/builder.rb:184:in `initialize'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290646+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:in `new'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290649+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290650+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/rack/builder.rb:170:in `eval'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290653+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/rack/builder.rb:170:in `new_from_string'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290656+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/rack/builder.rb:161:in `parse_file'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290657+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/configuration.rb:129:in `load_rackup'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290660+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/configuration.rb:96:in `app'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290663+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/runner.rb:113:in `load_and_bind'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290664+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/single.rb:79:in `run'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290667+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/cli.rb:215:in `run'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290670+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.13.4/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290673+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2015-09-10T02:51:04.290674+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
2015-09-10T02:51:05.232991+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-10T02:51:05.222998+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-09-10T02:52:34.037523+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=shop-bedepraved.herokuapp.com request_id=dad14f43-4299-4ad3-867
8-d8459f39e5f7 fwd="75.63.145.154" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-09-10T02:52:36.899552+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shop-bedepraved.herokuapp.com request_id=bfa45de4-4e
27-43a1-ad9d-17966e1394a3 fwd="75.63.145.154" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

heroku console

```
Running `console` attached to terminal... up, run.6655
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/spree-product-assembly-a932f58d19f2/app/serializers/spree/wombat/assembly_shipment_serializer.rb:3:in `<module:Wombat>': uninitiali
zed constant Spree::Wombat::ShipmentSerializer (NameError)
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/spree-product-assembly-a932f58d19f2/app/serializers/spree/wombat/assembly_shipment_serializer.rb:2:in `<module:Spree>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/spree-product-assembly-a932f58d19f2/app/serializers/spree/wombat/assembly_shipment_serializer.rb:1:in `<top (required)
>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
        from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:147:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:8:in `require'
        from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '2-4-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '2-4-stable'
gem "figaro"
# Fix for Taxon issue not displaying selected taxons
gem 'select2-rails'
gem 'spree_reffiliate'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'spree_bootstrap_frontend', github: '200Creative/spree_bootstrap_frontend', branch: 'master'
gem 'spree_product_assembly', github: 'spree-contrib/spree-product-assembly', branch: 'master'
gem 'puma'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.11'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

In my digging it does not look like I'm the only person who has run into this. https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree-product-assembly/issues/110

But it is closed and I'm not seeing a solution. I have tried to roll back to various commits, same issue. I switched to Puma, as I found somewhere saying to try that, it was not about my issue but it was close. This has been my headache for 4 days now, in desperate need of some help.

Thank you in advance!
Ian

Answer (score 0):

Well I got a response from the developers. The issue was never really fixed! They just installed spree_womabat even if you don't need it. Took me 30 seconds arg! Hope this save someone some time. Happy coding!

Comment: how do yo fixed it after installing the womabat gem ? it didn't just worked after installing the gem..